# Access 2010 VBA Too few parameters: Expected 3

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In VBA for Access 2010 and I am just trying to insert some data into a subform.  I have a form, with 3 subforms on it.  I have 3 unbound text boxes that the user will enter data, hit a command button, and then that data will instert into the subform I have on the layout.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdAssign_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Crew " _
    & "(txtCrewName,txtKitNumber,txtActionDate) VALUES " _
    & "(txtAssignCrew, txtAssignKit, txtAssignDate);"

End Sub
```

I know it has got to be something simple but I'm not really familiar with this.  The txtCrewName, txtKitNumber, and txtActionDate are the empty values in the subform where I want data to go.  And the txtAssignCrew, txtAssignKit, and txtAssignDate are the unbounds on the form, but outside of the subform 'Crew'.  Any ideas?  Thanks

EDIT:  Figured it out.  Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

So `txtAssignCrew`, `txtAssignKit`, and `txtAssignDate` are the names of controls on the form.  The db engine doesn't know what they are, so assumes they must be parameters.

You could build those controls' *values* (instead of the controls' names) into your `INSERT` statement.  But consider an actual parameter query instead, and execute it from a `QueryDef` object.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strInsert As String

strInsert = "PARAMETERS crew_name Text(255), kit_num Long, action_date DateTime;" & vbCrLf & _
    "INSERT INTO Crew (txtCrewName,txtKitNumber,txtActionDate)" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES (crew_name, kit_num, action_date);"
Debug.Print "strInsert:" & vbCrLf & strInsert
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("crew_name") = Me.txtAssignCrew
qdf.Parameters("kit_num") = Me.txtAssignKit
qdf.Parameters("action_date") = Me.txtAssignDate
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Note, in the `PARAMETERS` clause I assumed text as the data type for `txtCrewName`, long integer for `txtKitNumber`, and Date/Time for `txtActionDate`. If all are text, adjust the `PARAMETERS` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I put this new code in and I change that parameters all to text format just for testing reasons. Next, I got rid of all the 'txt' in the beginning of the names to look neater. Now I get an error though that saying "The INSERT INTO statements contains the following unknown field name: 'CrewName'. I have it typed correctly as I have been checking it over and over. Is there anyway I would have to change anything else or is it just a mispelling somehwere? EDIT: And if I get rid of CrewName, for instance, then it moves onto the next one saying 'KitNumber' is unknow.

Comment: I'm not sure but would suspect misspelling.  Try the insert as a new query in the query designer.  That should help you pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming txtAssignCrew, Kit, and Date are your unbound controls you want to insert. Realize that if there are single quotes or anything in those fields, it would cause the statement to fail, so you would need to escape them.

```
 Private Sub cmdAssign_Click()

 CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Crew " _
  & "(txtCrewName,txtKitNumber,txtActionDate) VALUES " _
  & "('" & me.txtAssignCrew & "', '" & me.txtAssignKit & "','" & me.txtAssignDate & ");"

 End Sub
```

I may have botched a quote.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I keep getting run-time error '3075' now.  It is in the textbox where I would put the date.  So it says, 'Syntax error in string in query expression "xxxx);'.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code:
CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Crew " _
    & "(txtCrewName,txtKitNumber,txtActionDate) VALUES " _
    & "('" & txtAssignCrew & "','" & txtAssignKit & "','" & txtAssignDate & ");"

Notes:
- You might need to change the format for the AssignDate parameter
- Column names in the database are usually not prefixed with txt
- You would be better off using parametized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I got rid of the txt on all the names.  I get an error now that CrewName (was txtCrewName) is an unknown field.  I made sure the spelling is all right, and even took out CrewName all together and left the other two.  Then the error just moved on down and said 'KitNumber' was now unknow.  Anything else that might be wrong?

Comment: What are the field-names in your table Crew? I assume they are not txtCrewName, etc.? So are they CrewName etc.? The items in the first bracket-set need to be the field-names in your table.

Comment: @Andy G, they are now CrewName, KitNumber, and ActionDate.  They are the names of the textboxes in my subform, Crew